# Do I drain my washing machine pump for long term winter storage?

Tags: water, washing-machine, pump, storage, winterizing

I'm putting my washing machine into storage for 10+ months in a garage that is not insulated and will experience sub-freezing temperatures for multiple months.

The question is: **should I drain the pump of all the water or not?**

I think I do because I don't want the water freezing.

However, I wasn't sure if I needed to intentionally leave some water in to keep parts moist/lubricated. (I think that's the case with some dishwasher seals if I recall).

Comment: UPDATE: I left this washer in storage in this insulation-less garage for 10 months with no water in it (i.e., completely drained). Sub-freezing temps obviously, then, did not matter since it was drained.  After 10mo in storage, I started using it normally again in a new home. It's been going fine for 2+ years since (and it was a 15+ year old model to begin with!). So I'd say draining it was fine -- prevented freezing for sure!! -- and all is well! :)

Answer (score 4):

IF you can drain it of all water, that would be good. Since this is often difficult, or requires major disassembly to achieve with any confidence, non-toxic RV antifreeze is another option to prevent damage.

Comment: Putting the discharge hose on the ground and allowing the water has worked for me to drain a washing machine. But the RV antifreeze would work also.

Comment: I actually already opened it up, disassembled the pump, and drained the whole thing. Easy 15 minute job with the open space of my garage. It was only after draining it that I wondered how many others would go through the effort (especially given the amount of water I spread everywhere!). It's only at *that* point that I began to wonder if any seals or anything actually should stay wet, and perhaps I'd need to put water back in!

Comment: No need for any seals to remain wet, it'll be fine. Much better than have a hose split from freezing, which I have experienced in a washer in an un-heated "outdoor" space